# I keep getting access denied when trying to use reg unload

Tags: powershell, registry, access-denied

I keep getting access denied when I try to use reg unload.

```
reg load hku\usersid "C:\users\username\ntuser.dat"
reg unload hku\usersid
```

I tried using the trash collector

```
[gc]::collect()
```

I also tried clearing variables

```
get-variable
clear-variable
remove-variable
```

I checked with ProcMon and found handles from the file "C:\users\username\ntuser.dat" connected to the process System. I am assuming that it is not unloading because of this, but I am unable to close the handle, that gives me an invalid error.

Is there no way other than rebooting the computer to use reg unload successfully? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.  Access denied is a permissions problem.

Comment: Yeah I figure it is because System is holding it and I do not have permission to supersede System, even though I am Domain Admin. But System is the all powerful xD

Guess I will just reboot the computer each time